# Bootstrap Accordion with image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with the accordion in my application.  I use bootstrap and pure css.
When the accordion is open, the arrow needs up, when is closed arrow needs down. But all time is arrow up.

Please, help me.

This is my code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Title 1 <span></span></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Title 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
       Title 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.toggle-img span {
 background: url(arrow_up.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 9px;
  width: 21px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#accordion .collapsed span {
  background: url(arrow_down.png) no-repeat !important;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 9px;
  width: 21px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you show a demo using codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/103657/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `<div>` not close, but the biggest problem I saw was the class "collapsed". If you add this class to all toggle-img by default (because all accordions, when I visit for the first time the page, are closed) the up&down arrows works well. In my example I used color: red=arrows up/ green=arrows down

```css
.toggle-img span {
  /*background-image: url("up.jpg");*/
  background-color:#00ff00;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 29px;
  width: 21px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#accordion .collapsed span {
  /*background-image: url("down.jpg");*/
  background-color:#ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height:29px;
  width: 21px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Title 1 <span></span></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Title 2<span></span></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="toggle-img collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
       Title 3<span></span></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ops. I did a mistake: green = arrow up | red = arrow down. Sorry (^_^;)

Comment: Glad to help you. If it works, please accetp the answer. Thank you. :)